# How to go about repairing Compile error - expected identifier

Tags: excel, vba

could someone point me in the right direction with the following error message please.
The first two lines are both highlighted in red:

```
Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, _

ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Public Const VK_SNAPSHOT = 44

Public Const VK_LMENU = 164

Public Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2

Public Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1
```

Our organisation uses an Excel add in to pull the information from the spreadsheet which will only work with 32bit office. I'm working off 2 laptops, on one I have no issues it works as it should but on the new laptop keeps coming up with expected identifier error.

Could someone help?

Comment: Remove the blank line between the two red-highlighted lines.

Comment: (@TimWilliams I take the blank line(s) to be an artefact from a new user not knowing how to use either markdown line breaks (append to blanks to preceding lines) or code blocks (enclose in lines containing just `~~~`.)

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering could be due to the incompatibility of 32-bit libraries with 64-bit versions of Office. If you're running this code on 64-bit Office, you'll need to declare your API calls as "PtrSafe".

Here's how you should declare your keybd_event for 64-bit Office:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)
#Else
    Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
#End If
```

The VBA7 conditional constant is True for Office 2010 and later, so this way your code will work for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office. Also, in 64-bit VBA, a LongPtr data type was introduced that can hold either a 32-bit or 64-bit memory address, depending on the version. In your case, dwExtraInfo should be a LongPtr.

You can modify all your API calls this way to ensure compatibility across 32-bit and 64-bit Office versions.

Please note that this fix assumes that you're encountering an issue because of a 32-bit vs 64-bit discrepancy. If the error persists, it might be due to another issue within your code.

Comment: Most likely OP is just seeing a syntax error caused by the blank line following the line continuation `_`...

Answer (score 0):

This is a compile-time error caused by the a blank line after the line-continuation character `_`

Can replicate this exactly as described:

[image]

Removing the blank line will fix the problem.